# Prove that $3$ and $4 \pm \sqrt{7}$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}] = a + b \sqrt{7}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, the problem is showing that 3 and $4 \pm \sqrt{7}$ are irreducible.

**My attempt**: Suppose that $3 = \alpha \beta$ and neither $\alpha$ or $\beta$ are units.

The norm $N(a + b \sqrt{7}) = (a + b \sqrt{7})(a - b \sqrt{7}) = a^2 - 7 b^2$ is integer valued and multiplicative.

We have that $N(3) = 9 = N(4 \pm \sqrt{7})$, hence if $3 = \alpha \beta$ then $N(\alpha) \in \{ 1, -1, 3, -3, 9, -9 \}$.

Let $\alpha = a + b \sqrt{7}$, then if $N(\alpha) = 1$ it must be a unit, since we would have that $1 = \alpha (a - b \sqrt{7})$, so this rules out the case $N(\alpha) = 1$ and $N(\alpha) = 9$ since then $\beta$ would be a unit.

If $N(\alpha) = -1$ then $-1 = a^2 - 7b^2$, projecting this equation on $\mathbb{Z}_7$ yields $6 = a^2$ but the map $x \to x^2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ maps $1 \to 1$, $2 \to 4$, $3 \to 2$, $4 \to 2$, $5 \to 4$, $6 \to 1$, so we have a contradiction, this rules out the cases $N(\alpha) = -1$ and $N(\alpha) = -9$.

By the same argument $N(\alpha) \not= 3$, so the only possibility is $N(\alpha) = -3 = N(\beta)$, so $a = 2$ or $5$ mod 7.

If $\beta = c + d\sqrt{7}$ we have $3 = ac + 7bd + \sqrt{7}(ad + bc)$, hence $3 = ac$ mod 7, we know that $a \not= c$ mod 7 since 3 is not a square, without loss of generality we would have $a = 2, c= 5$ then $ac = 3$ but I don't see any contradiction here.

Comment: $ac=10$ and $ac=3$?

Comment: @janmarqz OP was using mod 7 in the last paragraph.

Comment: Do we count $3 = (2+\sqrt7)(-2+\sqrt7)$?

Comment: Or $(5\pm2\sqrt7)(-2\pm\sqrt7) = 4\pm\sqrt7$?

Comment: I don't see why we shouldn't count them. Since I got this question from a qualification test I never even considered that it could be wrong.

Comment: Well, it did look fishy, ’cause both those quantities are of norm $9$, yet they clearly are not associates.